# get array variable value

Tags: javascript, html, indexof

The code below creates a form and appends array lists to a field set on submit. however, it only works if you enter a value of 0 to 3 in to the form rather that the actual text values from the array variable `ArrayName =['list1','list2','list3','list4']` 
 THIS LINE OF CODE: `var a = ArrayName.indexOf(form.url.value)` IS RETURNING the value -1 instead of the text input value.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

```
<font color = "Silver" size ="4">
<form onsubmit="return processForm(this);">
<input type="text" name="url" required="required"/>
<input type ="radio"name="SearchType" value ="SymbolSearch" id="SearchByEpic" checked     ="checked"/><font size=2>Symbol search

<input type ="radio"name="SearchType" value ="CompanySearch"/>Company name search
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</input></input>
</form><font color = "white">
<br><br>


<style media="screen" type="text/css">
fieldset{
border:0px solid gray;
padding:1em;
float:left;
font-family:Arial;
}
legend{
display:none;
}
h2{
border-bottom:2px solid gray;
margin:1em 0;
}
p{
margin:1em 0;
}
</style>

<div id="QuoteField">
<fieldset style="float: center; background-color:#313131; width:558px; height:318px;" >    <font size="4"><strong>
<br><br><br><br>
<li><p id="CompanyName"><font color=#21F1FE><strong>Company name: </p></li>

<li><p id="CompanyEpic"><font color=#21F1FE><strong>Stock symbol: </p></li>

<li><p id="CompanySector"><font color=#21F1FE>Sector: </p></li>
<li><p id="CompanySub">Sub sector: </p></li>

<br>
</fieldset></div>

<script type="text/javascript">var your_url = 'http://getquote=LLOY.L';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#QuoteField').hide();

var ArrayName = ['List1','List2','List3','List4']
var ArrayDate = ['28-03-1991', '28-09-2004', '01-01-1901', '12-05-2008']
var ArraySector = ['General Financial','Nonlife Insurance','Support Services','Oil     Equipmen']
var EpicSubSector = ['Asset Managers','Insurance Brokers','General Support','Oil     Equipment & Services']
var Epic=['stock1','stock2','stock3','stock4']


function processForm(form)
{
var somevalue = form.url.value;
var StockNum=0; 
var a = ArrayName.indexOf(form.url.value);
alert( a );
$('#QuoteField').show(500);
$('#CompanyName').html('<font color=#21F1FE><strong>Company name: ');
$('#CompanySub').html('Sub sector: ');
$('#CompanySector').html('Sector: ');
$('#CompanyEpic').html('Stock symbol: ');


// 

 if($('#SearchByEpic').attr('checked'))
{
$('#CompanyName').append('</strong><font color="white" size="2"</font>' + ArrayName[form.url.value] +'<strong>');
$('#CompanySub').append('</strong><font color="white" size="2"</font>' + ArrayDate[form.url.value]);
$('#CompanySector').append('</strong><font color="white" size="2">' + ArraySector[form.url.value]+ '</font>');
$('#CompanyEpic').append('</strong><font color="white" size="2">' +   Epic[form.url.value]+ '</font>');
}
else{alert("not epic search");$("#symbol").html("")
}

//window.open("http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=" + form.url.value,     "test window","width=100,height=100"); 

return false;
return false;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: the search is case sensitive, are you matching it exactly?

Comment: Ohh c'mon unclosed `<strong>` tags, Usage of the obsolete `<font>`, unclosed `<font>` tags... uninitialized `list` elements ... `return false` twice in your JS...

Comment: I guess someone didnt take breakfast today...

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code, it works just fine.

Minimal working example:

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return processForm(this);">
  <input type="text" name="url" required="required" value="List1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var ArrayName = ['List1', 'List2', 'List3', 'List4'];

function processForm(form) {
  var somevalue = form.url.value;
  var a = ArrayName.indexOf(form.url.value);
  alert(a);
  return false;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Ap9Gw/

Your code has plenty of errors, but nothing that I see would keep that part of the script from working.

Comment: Thanks, Found the issue. comparing arrays and variables with indexOf is case sensitive. is there a way around this?

Comment: @user3135160 Force everything to uppercase before comparison.

Comment: @user3135160: Us the `toUpperCase` method to convert the input to upper case, and use upper case in the Array: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Ap9Gw/1/